# Giving a table a name in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-table

I'm taking my first steps in org mode. In the spreadsheet section, they give an example:

```
$3 = remote(FOO, @@#$2)
```

Where FOO is another table. However, they don't explain how can I give a name to a table. Does any of you know how to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Put the line

```
#+NAME: FOO
```

immediately before the table.

This applies for all current versions of org, i.e. 8.x and later. For earlier versions of org, use

```
#+TBLNAME: FOO
```

Comment: This is #NAME: FOO in recent versions of org-mode, see http://orgmode.org/manual/References.html at the bottom.